# Where can I buy engraved LEGO bricks?

Tags: 3rd-party, customization

What is the cheapest site to buy engraved LEGO bricks?

I am searching for the cheapest site to buy engraved 2X4/2x6 bricks so that I can put names on them and send them to people. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Online I would recommend [BrickEngraver](http://www.brickprinter.com/)

I think your best bet would be to find a local trophy shop, most will engrave items.  Take them some LEGO to test and they should be able to provide what you need without the need to pay shipping.

Comment: +1 I think BrickEngraver was the company we used when we did the Brick Fiesta convention, and they turned out really nice.